# What is an n-cell?

Tags: general-topology, terminology, simplicial-complex

In my Topology lecture notes, 'n-cell' seems to be mentioned a lot, but it never says what exactly it means. Does it mean $n$-dimensional space?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-cell_(mathematics)

Comment: According to Rudin: "If $a_i<b_i$ for $i=1,\ldots,k$, the set of all points $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,\ldots,x_k)$ in $\mathbb{R}^k$ whose coordinates satisfy the inequalities $a_i\le x_i\le b_i$ ($1\le i\le k$) is called a $k$-cell." Verbatim.

Comment: Thanks! I tried to google n-cell, but couldn't find it.

Comment: This reminds me that I had a professor who used to call the $n$-cell "$n$-pavé".

One also liked to call it $k$-box.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a homeomorphic copy of the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$. One common way of building/decomposing topological spaces is by starting with $0$-cells (points) and gluing in successively higher dimensional cells along their boundaries. Spaces which can be realized this way are called [cell complexes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CW_complex).