# Spaces homeomorphic to unit cube

Tags: general-topology

Is there any specific name in the literature for spaces homeomorphic to unit cube in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: That is just the $n$-ball.

Comment: ... or the $(n-1)$-sphere, if "$n$-cube" is intended to include only the faces and not the interior.

Comment: Also called an $n$-cell, I believe.  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1486259/what-is-an-n-cell

Comment: There is no specific name that I know of. Saying $n$-ball or $n$-cube or $n$-cell doesn't cover all the possibilities: e.g., none of them applies to a dodecahedron. "Convex body" doesn't cover it either.

Comment: I'll never understand this obsession with names. In bronze age, that was important, name magic, you know, while in mathematics, there are definitions and theorems... wait, I see: how can you *google* it, without a name?! :p

Comment: @RobArthan Why not?  The question was for the homeomorphism type, and the dodecahedron is obviously homeomorphic to a 3-cell.

Comment: @user10354138: the question is asking for a name that covers all elements of the homotopy type not just some of them.

Comment: @RobArthan where does homotopy type come in?  If we are talking about homotopy type than contractible would cover all.

Comment: @user10354138: sorry. Mental typo: it should read homeomorphism type.